# STM32f2xx external clock source for timer

Tags: c, stm32, clock, timer

I trying to use a timer with an external clock source on a stm32f207ZE microcontroller.
But it isn't working. Here is my code:

```
  /* TIM1 clock enable */
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM1, ENABLE);

  /* GPIOE clock enable */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOE, ENABLE);

  /* GPIOE Configuration: PE.11(TIM1 CH2)  */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_11;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_TIM1);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_TIM1);

  /* TIM1 Input trigger configuration: External Trigger connected to TI2 */
  TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_Channel = TIM_Channel_2;
  TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity = TIM_ICPolarity_Rising;
  TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;
  TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV2;
  TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter = 0x0;
  TIM_ICInit(TIM1, &TIM_ICInitStructure);

  TIM_TIxExternalClockConfig (TIM1, TIM_TS_TI2FP2, TIM_ICPolarity_Rising, 0) ;
  TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM1, TIM_SlaveMode_External1);

  TIM_Cmd (TIM1, ENABLE);
```

Where can be my mistake? I have some misunderstanding on what source pin must be used for Timer1 TI2. Is it the same that Timer1_CH2?

I also tried ETR mode by inizializing ETR pin

```
  /* TIM1 clock enable */
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM1, ENABLE);

  /* GPIOE clock enable */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOE, ENABLE);


    /* GPIOE Configuration: PE.7(TIM1 ETR)  */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_TIM1);

    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 0xFFFF;      // 5000*20 uS - 100 ms
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 0;    // frequency - 20 MHz
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM1, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure); 

    //for ETR IN RM0033 p. 372
    TIM1->SMCR = 0;
    TIM1->SMCR |= TIM_ExtTRGPSC_DIV4; //2. set prescaller
    TIM1->SMCR |= TIM_ICPolarity_Rising; //3. rising edge
    TIM1->SMCR |= 0x4000; // 4. Enable external clock mode 2 by writing ECE=1

  TIM_Cmd (TIM1, ENABLE);
```

But it also doesn't work. Maybe frequency is to high? And i saw some strnge behaviour. When i inizialize once more counter:

```
void inizializeSimpleCounter(){
  NVIC_InitTypeDef                  NVIC_InitStructure;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef     TIM_TimeBaseStructure;

/****************Timer4 Inizialization**************************/
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM4, ENABLE);

    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 5000;        // 5000*20 uS - 100 ms
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 3-1;  // frequency - 20 MHz
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM4, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure); 

    TIM4->DIER = TIM_DIER_UIE;

    TIM_Cmd(TIM4, ENABLE);

    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel =  TIM4_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x01;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x03;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE; 
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
/*************************************************************/

}
```

The timer, which was initialize to count from extrenal counter counts some values, and then stops

Comment: It might be helpful if you described current behavior versus the expected behavior

Comment: Some external source with frequency 20 MHz is connected to this pin. I expext that counter will begin to count - so the value in TIM1->CNT register will increment. But nothing counts

Comment: It seems that error was in schematic. Inizialization is right

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but solved it with the code below:

```
TIM2->SMCR =0x0067;
TIM2->CCMR1=0x0100;
TIM2->CCER=0x0010;
TIM2->CNT = 0x1;
```

Comment: I've formatted your answer but it might be worth adding a further explanation of what the code does and why it works versus the original.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM1, TIM_TS_ETRF);

Function. For me works with first yours example.